# Cefsharp initializing for the second time throws error

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

My application needs to invoke (off screen) browser on request and cleanup once it is done.

So I created an offscreen browser

```
 public class OffScreenBrowser 
{
    private static ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;

    private static CefSettings _settings;

    public void Load(string url,System.Drawing.Size size)
    {
        if (Cef.IsInitialized) return;
        Init(new BrowserProcessHandler());

        _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url) {Size = size};
        _browser.NewScreenshot += _browser_NewScreenshot;
    }
    public System.Windows.Controls.Image BrowserImage { get; set; }
    public Action NewScreenShotAction { get; set; }

    private void _browser_NewScreenshot(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bitmap = _browser.ScreenshotOrNull();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();

                BrowserImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image() {Source = bitmapImage};
                NewScreenShotAction();
            }
        }));
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _browser.NewScreenshot -= _browser_NewScreenshot;
        _browser.Dispose();
        _settings.Dispose();
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }

    public static void Init(IBrowserProcessHandler browserProcessHandler)
    {
        _settings = new CefSettings();
        if (!Cef.Initialize(_settings, true, browserProcessHandler))
            throw new Exception("Unable to Initialize Cef");
    }
}
```

The idea is-on clicking a button create browser and on clicking another button close the browser

```
private OffScreenBrowser offScreenBrowser;

private void OPen_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var address = @"https://www.google.co.uk";
    var width = 200;
    var height = 100;
    var windowSize = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);
     offScreenBrowser = new OffScreenBrowser();
    offScreenBrowser.Load(address, windowSize);

    offScreenBrowser.NewScreenShotAction = () => 
    {
        Browser.Content = offScreenBrowser.BrowserImage;
    };
}

private void Close_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    offScreenBrowser.Close();
}
```

On the first click it all works fine. On clicking close it seems like the cleanup is fine.

But when I click the open button for the second time I am getting an exception as below

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in CefSharp.Core.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown

Comment: Looked into this and seems no help there. By the way,in the official offscreen example in git if you shutdown CEF and attempt to init again the system will exit. So looks like once shutdown is done there is something preventing it from starting for the second time

Comment: Never mind. The issue was the shutdown call. We can create and destroy ChromiumWebBrowser.  But init and  shutdown is single calls for the lifetime of application. Thank you

Comment: As a general reference https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/421#comment-16410312

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation in Chromium framework.

CEF can only be Initialized/Shutdown once per process,
See [Need to Know/Limitations](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitations) for more details, this is a limitation of the underlying Chromium framework.

Comment: how about if a single form (WPF) implementing the initialization once and shutting down also once, but that form is called multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

to solve this you can call the `Cef.Initialize` in the start form and you need to call it only once in your application
the you can call `ChromiumWebBrowser` many times inside any for of your application forms
it worked for me